# 'java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation:' error occurred when restarting Springboot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a simple [Springboot project](https://github.com/krivochenko/spring-restart)

I made settings in my IntelliJ IDE:

1. Enable `compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running` checkbox in Registry
2. Enable `Build project automatically` in Compiler settings.

Not always but very often when I change my code and save it, I have error:

```
2018-11-23 05:25:10.544 ERROR 344 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "ru.krivochenko.demo.user.UserService.getNewUser()Lru/krivochenko/demo/user/User;" the class loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @6ce6e730 (instance of org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader, child of 'app' jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader) of the current class, ru/krivochenko/demo/MainController, and the class loader 'app' (instance of jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader) for the method's defining class, ru/krivochenko/demo/user/UserService, have different Class objects for the type ru/krivochenko/demo/user/User used in the signature] with root cause
```

[Full stack trace](https://gist.github.com/krivochenko/bda326f24ffd4a237cc1ecfa11265095)

Thanks for help!

Comment: I download your code and run,it works fine

Comment: Try to change it several times

Comment: Once you hit the error, copy the code and paste here

Comment: I have already attached full stack trace of error: https://gist.github.com/krivochenko/bda326f24ffd4a237cc1ecfa11265095

Comment: Is the code you provided is where the error happened ?

Comment: Simple changing `return new User(3, name);` to `return new User(1, name);` in UserService causes (not always) error which stack trace I provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason after rebuild changed class there is a time-gap before it really exists. 
I played a little bit with values in application.properties I found result working for me:

`spring.devtools.restart.poll-interval=3000
spring.devtools.restart.quiet-period=2999`